# If $A\in\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R)$, then $|A_j|\le C\|A\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a real $d\times m$ matrix. Let's denote $A_j$ its $j-th$ line, which is an element of $\Bbb R^m$.

Denote then with $|A_j|$ the euclidean norm of a vector and let $\|A\|:=\sup\{|Au|:u\in\Bbb S_{m-1}\}$ be the usual operator norm. Now, this last one is a norm on the $\Bbb R$-algebra $\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R)$ of all $d\times m$ real matrices.

Now it's clear that $\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R)\simeq\Bbb R^{d\times m}$ as vector spaces and we can define the above norm on $\Bbb R^{d\times m}$ via this isomorphism. But on this last space, we can consider also the euclidean norm (given a $A\in\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R)$, we continue to call A the correspondent element of $\Bbb R^{d\times m}$ and we can denote with $|A|$ the euclidean norm) and since all norms are equivalent when the dimension is finite, in particular there exists an absolute constant $C>0$ such that
$$
|A|\le C\|A\|\;\;\;\forall A\in\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R).
$$
Thus, it's clear that
$$
|A_j|\le|A|\le C\|A\|\;\;\;\forall A\in\mathcal M_{d,m}(\Bbb R).
$$

Do you agree?

My question is: how can we prove that $|A_j|\le C\|A\|$ with linear algebra methods?

I know that the operator norm of a matrix $A$ is the square root of the biggest eigenvalue of the symmetric matrix $A^TA$; now if it was $AA^T$, (which is different!) we would have in the diagonal the norms of $|A_j|$, and from this we can conclude. So a second question is: what is the relation between the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and the eigenvalues of $AA^T$?

Answer (score 1):

For any submultiplicative norm we have $\|AB \| \le \|A\| \|B\|$.

Hence $\|A_j\|_2 = \| e_j^T A\| \le \|e_j^T\|_2 \|A\|_2$.

As an aside, it is straightforward to show that the non zero eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are the same as $A^TA$. This is true even if $A$ is non square.